# Dropdown selected option changes color and a gap between the container and search-box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I was able to change the background color of the selected option but it changes its color after I have hovered over any other option.

Is there a way to control this and how can I get rid of this annoying space between the results search-box and container even though it doesnt appear in the code snippet.

[image: Selected option changing its color]

**The code**

```css
#bap + .select2 .select2-selection__rendered {
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* Each result */
#select2-bap-results {
  background-color: salmon;
}

/* Higlighted (hover) result */
#select2-bap-results .select2-results__option--highlighted {
  background-color: rgb(5, 27, 27) !important;
}

/* Selected option */
#select2-bap-results .select2-results__option[aria-selected="true"] {
  background-color: rgb(13, 14, 14) !important;
}

/* Around the search field */
.select2-search {
  background-color: orange;
}

/* Search field */
.select2-search input {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  



  <!-- -->

</head>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/search" method="get" class="d-flex w-25">
    <select id="bap" class="select2" style="width: 100%;" name="state">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
 
</form>

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
 
 <script>$(document).ready(function () {
      $('.select2').select2();
    });



  </script>
```

**Solution for the annoying "blank space"**
Added more line height to the element
`#bap + .select2 .select2-selection__rendered {}`

Comment: Are you new to select2, by chance? ... the `annoying space` is a search input added by select2 for selects that could have a very long list of options. (so that a user can avoid scrolling a long list) to remove that, you can do: `$('.select2').select2({ minimumResultsForSearch: -1});` ... and the gray background is the currently-selected option, when you hover away to other options.

Comment: @PaulT. I know why the gray background is there but the problem is it wouldnt fit my theme so I would want to change or do something about it.. Yes I am quite new to it.

Comment: So is it only the gray part for the selected option to cover? ... what is the desired color?

Comment: @PaulT.Yes, only that. Well then I would see what would fit the best but anything other than this gray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this CSS to change the selected option background color that appears with the gray background: (I simply used green for the example)

```
#select2-bap-results .select2-results__option--selected {
    background-color: green;
}
```

That change applied to the runnable example below:

```css
#bap + .select2 .select2-selection__rendered {
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* Each result */
#select2-bap-results {
  background-color: salmon;
}

/* Higlighted (hover) result */
#select2-bap-results .select2-results__option--highlighted {
  background-color: rgb(5, 27, 27) !important;
}

/* Selected option */
#select2-bap-results .select2-results__option[aria-selected="true"] {
  background-color: rgb(13, 14, 14) !important;
}

/* Around the search field */
.select2-search {
  background-color: orange;
}

/* Search field */
.select2-search input {
  background-color: pink;
}

#select2-bap-results .select2-results__option--selected {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  
  <!-- -->

</head>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/search" method="get" class="d-flex w-25">
    <select id="bap" class="select2" style="width: 100%;" name="state">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
 
</form>

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
 
 <script>$(document).ready(function () {
      $('.select2').select2();
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: Yes that changes the color of the selected and it stays the same, thanks! Although I did not mean the search bar itself in the dropdown I mean the little "black space" between the dropdown menu and the container. It is only visible in the pictures I have added.

Comment: Oh, you mean the portion between the select itself and the list of options? ... Based on only appearing in the image, I'm guessing that it is not present when rendered on the page?

Comment: No it is visible when its rendered in the page.. just not in the code snippet.. I just added some line height to the `#bap + .select2 .select2-selection__rendered {}` and this took away the space.  Now there is another problem - the borders of the input which is behind the actual select input is showing. [link](https://imgur.com/a/Wdvd6jV)

Comment: Solved it! got the right class for the input and took of its borders `.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
  border: none !important;
}` Thank you so much Paul!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. I do not see that space myself with the code copied out to a separate file with Firefox or Chrome, but good to know that you found a fix.